# Java: Stopping a thread that has run for too long?

Tags: java, multithreading

Say I've got something like this

```
public void run(){
    Thread behaviourThread = new Thread(abstractBehaviours[i]);
    behaviourThread.start();
}
```

And I want to wait until abstractBehaviours[i] run method has either finished or run for 5000 milliseconds. How do I do that? behaviourThread.join(5000) doesn't seem to do that afaik (something is wrong with my code and I've put it down to that).

All the abstract abstractBehaviour class is of course Runnable. I don't want to implement it inside each run method as that seems ugly and there are many different behaviours, I'd much rather have it in the calling/executing thread and do it just once.

Solutions? First time doing something as threaded as this. Thanks!

edit: So the interrupting solution would be ideal (requiring minimal changes to AbstractBehaviour implementations). BUT I need the thread to stop if it has finished OR 5000 milliseconds have passed so something like the following would not work because the thread may finish before the while loop in the parent thread has. Make sense? Any ways around this, I'd love to do it from within the thread that starts the threads obviously.

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
behaviourThread.start();
while(!System.currentTimeMilis - startTime < 5000);
behaviourThread.interrupt();
try {
    behaviourThread.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

edit: nevermind I see there is a Thread.isAlive() method, all solved I think

Comment: @John: that matches his question - except for the title, which talks about *stopping* a thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use the thread interrupt mechanism.  The worker thread / Runnable needs to periodically call [`Thread.interrupted()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted()) to see if it is time to stop.  The second part of the equation is that a separate thread needs to call [`Thread.interrupt()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()) on the worker thread after 5000 milliseconds have elapsed.

The advantages of using thread interrupts (over a bespoke solution using flags) include:

- The `interrupted()` state is always available for the current thread. You don't need to pass around an object handle or use a singleton.
- An interrupt will unblock some blocking IO and synchronization requests.  A bespoke solution cannot do this.
- Third-party Java applications and libraries may respect `Thread.interrupt()`.

**EDIT** - as a commenter points out, you can test whether the current thread has been interrupted using either `Thread.interrupted()` or `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`.  The main difference between the two approaches is that the former clears the interrupted flag, but the latter doesn't.

Comment: I would prefer isInterrupted() since it does not rely on the interruption flag like interrupted()

Comment: @Karussell - for the record, both isInterrupted() and interrupted() "rely on" the interruption flag.  The difference is that isInterrupted() does not reset the flag.

Comment: I've edited my post with the problems interrupting. Hopefully it's clearer now or maybe I've missed something? Thanks to everyone who has responded so far though, one solution I'm certain would work (but take longer to change the code). The other (interrupting) I'm probably just missing something/being dense.

Comment: that was that what I meant. So using interrupted() is a bit 'dangerous'

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this externally from the run method - the run method must check some variable to see if it should exit. For example:

```
class InterruptableRunnable implements Runnable
{
   private volatile boolean stop;
   public setStop() {
       stop = true;
   }

   public void run() {
        while (!stop)
        {
            //do some work and occassionaly fall through to check that stop is still true
        }
   }
}
```

The key thing is for the code in the run loop to check the stop flag occasionally. You can then wire up a timer to set stop to true after 5000 milliseconds.

Finally, it's best practice not to use Threads directly, use the excellent Concurrency Framework. The [Concurrency Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) is a good place to start and the book [Java Concurrency in practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/) is excellent.

Comment: +1 and you can include the timing limit in the while loop statement via System.currentMillis or so

Answer (score 2):

You may do it using java.util.concurrent package.

```
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    Future future = service.submit(behaviourThread);

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (!future.isDone()) {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > 5000) {
            future.cancel(true);
            break;
        }
    } 
    // TODO: more work here

    //don't forget to shutDown your ThreadPool
    service.shutDown();
```

This code will stop your thread after 5 seconds if it has not finished it's job by that time. If you check ***behaviourThread.isAlive()*** it's gonna show **false**.

Comment: Interesting. I see where an Executer may or may not spawn another thread.

Answer (score -1):

You do that by implementing a Runnable

```
public void run()
{
  long time = System.nanoTime(),
       end  = time + 5 000 000 000; // just better formatting
  do {
    ...my code

  } while (System.nanoTime() < end && myOwnCondition);
}
```

- Interrupt is not such a good solution, because you need to access the thread from outside
  and it disturbs the program flow. The thread can terminate anytime in your code which
  makes cleanup difficult. Please form a habit of letting threads run to the end because  otherwise it opens nasty and difficult bugs.
- If your program is so heavy duty that you don't know that the while end is reached until the task has completed I suggest the use of a labeled break:

  ```
  do {
    breakout:
    {
      ..my code
      if (timetest)
        break breakout;      
    }
    // cleanup
    ...
  } while (...);
  ```

Comment: Not responding to an interrupted exception is the biggest mistake you can make in concurrent programming.  You will notice so many of the j.u.c classes throw and handle interrupted exceptions.  In real world programming not only is interrupted exception a good solution its usually the best solution.  If someone handles interruption correctly then there wouldnt be those bugs you are suggesting